# Win10 file created without any ownership/permission at all

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I was editing some file in Photoshop and all of a sudden - without any sort of error or anything, normal work as always - I was unable to save the file, so I did "Save As" and then I went and look what is going on with the original file which I cannot edit, open nor delete anymore now although I'm the administrator: I've checked its Properties > Security and found out the file has absolutely no ownership/group/permission at all - that tab is completely blank; not even clicking the Advanced button there helps as it says I do not have permission which cannot be added as there is no identity in the PC that would have ownership of that file etc (closed self-acclaimed loop without any way out).

Also, the file has attribute of "N".

How something like this could happened? How to delete this file?

OR THE BEST SOLUTION WOULD BE to show me if it is somehow possible to add the security permissions back to the file (as there are absolutely none at the moment thus the file is unusable - one cannot open it, edit it nor delete it).

BTW the SSD that the file is on is still quite new, like 6 months old or so (3TB SSD).

[image Properties > Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA4nk.jpg)

[image Properties > Security > Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWA3v.jpg)

[image Properties > Security > Advanced > Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7a3Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never encountered such an error, but it seems like something
is wrong with the disk.
Such an error should be worrying, and you should
do all the checks possible.

Below are some suggestions:

- Save the updated file somewhere else, in case this file is
  irrecoverable
- Check the other files in the containing folder and the folder
  itself, to see if they are correct and if the problem is with
  one file only
- Take backup of your data, because the following steps can be
  destructive
- Run `chkdsk`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Check the SMART attributes of the disk
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours, even
  overnight
- Check the Event Viewer for messages relating to the hardware.

If nothing is found :

- Delete the file and replace it by the updated version
- If it can't be deleted, try it when booting in Safe mode
- Try to rename it and ignore it in the future
- Try to delete it from a Live boot USB, possibly using Linux.

Comment: I already know about the option to delete it via the USB loaded OS - thank you anyway, but I wanted to know what is the cause (looks like a 10yrs old 128GB SSD, but it happens on another SSD, not the system one)  and how to avoid it cos it may happen that there might come time when I do not register it is corrupted, close PS editor and I am done for good as such file would not be openable/editable anymore! :-((( Also I was hoping there is some way of adding the permission...

Comment: I don't think there is way to undo what happened. To avoid future errors on the disk, keep an eye on the hardware SMART attributes. I don't know if it pertains to your case, but many disk glitches are caused by power surges or cuts, so check also this angle. Also, a new disk can have issues - being new doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: In fact, I DO HAVE PROBLEMS WITH THE MB LATELY (its 15yrs+ old :D :D :D ) causing to PC to boot like only after like 5-6 tries. There is prolly something with the powering the old thing as I had to remove 2 DDR out of 4 cos it would not even boot if there were 4 of them! But the disk is quite new like 6 months - it is 3TB SDD. That 10yrs old is the OS SSD.

Comment: If you can find no problem with the disk, this might be the first danger sign for this old computer. Be careful with backups and check regularly.

Comment: I cannot sign it as a solution, cause it is not a solution: yes, there are some helpful advices I agree, but I am still waiting for some real solution like a way to add a security permission back to the file so I can manipulate it (edit/open/delete) "normal way".  ;-)

Comment: You could try using the [takeown command](https://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) on this file, on condition that the enclosing folder is ok. If it cannot fix the file, then I doubt that the rights can be restored.

Comment: In the end I decided to set your answer as the correct one, cos you were the 1st suggesting to use `chkdsk` although it was only the 2nd replier who actually made me to try it and make any use of it...which turned out to be the "solution" fixing some system issue showing me the file still tho it was in fact most prolly deleted already during  those issues I had with it as it wasn't basically there anymore at that very moment, strange (some sort of system visual glitch or whatever). :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How something like this could happened?

I'm mostly guessing towards filesystem corruption (run a chkdsk; reboot the system as well), or if not that, then your antivirus program being weird; but it's in theory possible to achieve by normal means if the program specifies an empty "security descriptor" when creating the file.

> which cannot be added as there is no identity in the PC that would have ownership of that file etc (closed self-acclaimed loop without any way out).

Administrators can always *take* ownership of any file regardless of its permissions, assigning either themselves or the whole "Administrators" group, as a system-level privilege. The `takeown` tool uses this.

Once an owner, the administrator can set a new ACL ignoring the old one. (Having ownership implicitly grants this permission, and the "takeown" operation even removes any special "Creator rights" ACLs that might deny it.)

```
takeown /f foo.psd
icacls foo.psd /reset
```

Additionally, Administrators can use another system privilege to *set* arbitrary owners and ACLs, or to just delete the file outright (SeRestorePrivilege allows bypassing write-permission checks); this is what Explorer uses to set custom owners, and PowerShell also uses it to delete files without having the 'Delete' permission.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong about the 2nd part: THERE IS ABSOLUTELLY NO PERMISSION AT ALL UNDER THE SECURITY TAB, I've already said that, so no: although I am admin I cannot do nothing with the file: SECURITY tab permission section is COMPLETELLY EMPTY, there is no way how to add it cos clicking on the Advanced tab will say I do not have ownership and cannot claim it as I do not have reading permission etc!!!

Comment: The whole point of my post was that there are system privileged allowing you to do it *without* file-level permissions. Run `takeown` on the file, then set new ACLs with `icacls /reset`.

Comment: I have no clue what that is - I am not a professional, just an ordinary girl, sorry: if you think it could be done "your" way, please, be so kind and post some applicable and easy to follow solution step-by-step as it is normally done in here, not just some statement that I am unable to take nothing form it although I do understand you meant it well, it is just that I am unable understand it like this.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you probably updated your post while I was replaying. Anyway: `takeown /f foo.psd` produces `ERROR: Access denied` as I already said several times NO ONE - ME (USER),SYSTEM,ADMIN, NOONE (the SECURITY tab with permissions is COMPLETELLY BLANK) - has any permission to the file itself! bah...thus I think your solution does not work. Just check those 3 pictures in my post to see for yourself...

Comment: And as I mentioned several times, the mechanism takeown uses *doesn't care* about file permissions – that's in fact the whole purpose of takeown; it specifically exists to let admins restore from such situations. Does it work if you're running it from an elevated console ("Run as administrator")? If not, then it's not a file permission problem – it's far more likely to outright be a filesystem corruption problem, since that kind of file doesn't normally show up on its own.

Comment: Of course I run CMD as admin. But if it is a filesystem corruption, could it be that just its header is corrupted (as I can check it still has the correct filezise = 111MB)? thus, if we know what header .psd file have, could it be manipulated somehow to repair it? Just guessing.

Comment: Then I'm 95% sure it's caused by something else than file permissions (i.e. the permission list is not merely empty but feels more like the OS itself isn't able to load it from disk). Run a `chkdsk /scan` or the full `chkdsk /f`, let it check the filesystem, then try again. (Will have to run a chkdsk regardless, even for the alternative plan of using Linux to delete it.)

Comment: So I finally did `chkdsk /scan`, it found some problems, I rebooted and now...the file is gone! From which I am deducting, that I have already deleted the file (I did click the file and DELETE but it remained unchanged, being still there in the Epxlorer itself) but for some reason it was still reported as present (like the file is already gone, but the visual stucked for some reason showing the file as still being there) - I think that could explain all that "nonsense" I was experiencing. After all, it look something in OS is not right, but I am not going to investigate, gee.